# Office 365: powershell script to uninstall the sharepoint app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I need the powershell script to uninstall the sharepoint app from office 365 site. I tried below script did not work for me.

```
    $getinstances = Get-SPAppInstance -Web https://spnote.sharepoint.com
    $getapp = $getinstances  | where {$_.Title -eq 'ArchiveDocs.app'} 
    Uninstall-SPAppInstance -Identity $getapp
```

Comment: Check out these 2 links https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Remove-all-app-instances-ae53934c            http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ocarpen/archive/2012/08/15/scripts-to-install-update-or-uninstall-a-sharepoint-2013-app-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply Manish!! But I want to know the issue with the current code.. I hope this should also work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Get-SPAppInstance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219678.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) cmdlet along with [another cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219772.aspx) are supported in SharePoint **On-Premises only**, they are **not** supported in **Office 365**.

The following script demonstrates how uninstall App in **SharePoint Online**:

> Prerequisites: [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-ClientContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}


Function Uninstall-AppInstance([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[Guid]$AppInstanceId)
{
    $appInst = $Context.Web.GetAppInstanceById($AppInstanceId)
    $appInst.Uninstall()
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
 }



$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"
$AppInstanceid = New-Object Guid("XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")  #specify App Instance Id here

$context = Get-ClientContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Uninstall-AppInstance -Context $context -AppInstanceId $AppInstanceid
$context.Dispose()
```

**How to get App Instance Id**

1. Go to Site Settings
2. Click a `...` link for an App and click `Details` menu item (see picture below)
3. Once the detail page will be opened, App Instance Id could be
   grabbed from Url: 
   `/_layouts/15/AppMonitoringDetails.aspx?AppInstanceId=<AppInstanceId>`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vadim. This is working for me. Only change that i made in my code is to get the app using product id as i am unable to find the appinstace id. I will appreciate if you can let me know how i can see the appinstance id of my custom App.

Comment: Sure, see the updated answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The above method to get the App Instance ID only works if the app is installed, & you are able to get to its details page. I ran into an issue where the app was partially removed & when trying to reinstall I saw this message

> "You can't add this app here."

I couldn't go to the App Details page, as described in Vadim's answer, to get the App Instance ID.

So, I got the App Instance Id from this page instead
https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/AppTiles

1. Goto above link & Save the XML
2. Open the xml in IE(or other xml reader) and search for your App's title
3. Under the `<entry>` tag, look for a GUID in the `<d:AppId>` tag. This is the App Instance ID you are looking for.

Run Vadim's script above, with the app instance id, to remove the app in the limbo state. After I did this, the "You can't add this app here." message was cleared & I could reinstall the app.

Hope this helps someone out. I wanted to post this as a comment to Vadim's answer, but stackexchange rules won't allow me.