# How to remove an App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

This may be a newbie question or it may be an oversight by Microsoft. Most likely the former, so if somebody could instruct me on how to Remove an App from the Modern view (Site Contents), that would be much appreciated. I'm using SharePoint Online.

**Classic View:**

[image: Classic SharePoint App removal]

**Modern View:**

[image: Modern View. How do I remove an app?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the official documentation on how to remove an App however it looks to be out-dated.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Remove-an-app-from-a-site-03198d1b-c33b-498d-9469-af641a587d6c

What looks like an oversight on Microsoft's part that this option is missing when in the "Modern" view.

You can click the **"Return to classic SharePoint"** bottom right then remove the app in the normal way.

[image: No option to Remove apps / add-ons in the Modern SharePoint View]

(If you close and re-open the browser you will be back in Modern view).

I hope they correct the documentation soon and also fix this bug before removing the ability to switch back to "Classic SharePoint"

Answer (score 1):

```
Prerequisites: SharePoint Online Client Components SDK

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-ClientContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}


Function Uninstall-AppInstance([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[Guid]$AppInstanceId)
{
    $appInst = $Context.Web.GetAppInstanceById($AppInstanceId)
    $appInst.Uninstall()
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
 }



$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"
$AppInstanceid = New-Object Guid("XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")  #specify App Instance Id here

$context = Get-ClientContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Uninstall-AppInstance -Context $context -AppInstanceId $AppInstanceid
$context.Dispose()
```

[Office 365: powershell script to uninstall the sharepoint app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142793/office-365-powershell-script-to-uninstall-the-sharepoint-app)

Comment: I like Powershell and I shall test it supermode, but is there really no way in modern view?

Comment: you should normally have the option to delete. perhaps check your permission. http://www.instantquick.com/index.php/how-to-install-and-uninstall-apps-from-the-sharepoint-store-on-office-365?c=elumenotion-blog-archive/sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-apps

Comment: That link only shows how to delete from Classic View. +2 if you can find me an answer for Modern view