# Cannot delete the App added in Site Contents

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, administration, spfx-webparts, app

We added a SPFX App in a SharePoint 2019 on-premise environment but somehow got an error. The problem is we cannot remove the app from the Site Contents. What possibly is the cause and how can we remove it? Thanks!

Here is the image of what it looks like.

[image]

When it is in classic mode:

[image]

**Update:**

We tried different PowerShell scripts like Uninstall-SpAppInstance but we were getting an unknown error.

The solution we found will be found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142793/office-365-powershell-script-to-uninstall-the-sharepoint-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Uninstall-SPAppInstance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/uninstall-spappinstance?view=sharepoint-ps) to uninstall the app.

Comment: Hi, We were getting an unknown error when using uninstall--spappinstance. It was stuck in Uninstalling status. Anyway, we already found a solution. Thank you for your help.